# Fourier Algebra of the Direct Limit of Groups

Tags: harmonic-analysis

I'm searching for a particular result or discussion, and was hoping either someone here could refer me to a paper or book, or tell me I'm fine in not being able to find this thing. I'm looking to see if there is a way of constructing the Fourier Algebra for the direct limit of groups from the Fourier algebras of the individual groups.

Comment: Have you checked the book by Kaniuth & Lau? You may find the corollary on p.71 helpful: https://books.google.ca/books?id=RmhjDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA71

Comment: I actually have seen that corollary; doesn't the corollary just say that A(G) contains copies of A(H) when H is a closed subgroup? It doesn't necessarily give the structure of the whole A(G) in terms of knowing the A(H)? Unless there's something else I'm missing.

Comment: Yes, but you have not only a single subgroup but a direct system of groups $(G_i)$ and connecting maps (continuous homomorphisms) $\phi_{ij}:G_i\to G_j$. Let's assume $\phi_{ij}$ are 1-1, so WLOG $G_i$ is a subgroup of $G_j$ when $i<j$. Thus there's a corresponding direct system of $(A(G_i))$ and an inverse system of $(A(G_i))$ with the maps given by the corollary. For general noninjective $\phi_{ij}$, perhaps this construction can be adapted.

Comment: Got it; my adviser may also have had this suspicion, but we haven't had a chance to discuss this yet! In our case the connecting maps are (basically) injective inclusions (not direct inclusions, but injective isomorphisms to subgroups).